# Difference of 'meaning' and 'sense' of words

Tags: word-choice

When a dictionary entry for a word has many items, which of the following is more appropriate to use?

- *the word has many meanings* or
- *the word has many senses*

My impression is that the first is more common.

However, when talking about what is meant by such words, I have the impression it is more idiomatic to use like

- *The word is used in the first sense*
- *The word is used in the sense ....*

Am I correct about these? Or *meaning/sense* are interchangeable above?

Are there rules when to use *meaning* and when to use *sense*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your feelings about those words are correct. I'd just add one to the pile: "definition".

When referring specifically to a word like that in a dictionary, we say it has many **definitions** or many **meanings**.

When talking about a word, but not about its dictionary entry, we say it has many **meanings**.

When talking about a particular usage of a word, we say it is used in a particular **sense**.